# need a live cd to boot to ram

Tags: live-usb, live-cd, custom-distributions, uck, boot-to-ram

I created a live cd using uck and want it to boot to ram by default.  How can I do this?  I know I can hit f6 while booting and insert toram=yes, but like I mentioned I want this to be setup by default.  Thanks in advance.  Also I am a rookie when it comes to setting up ubuntu so more detailed instructions are needed.

Comment: Live CDs using file storage in RAM anyway.  What specific needs do you have that can't be satisfied by the normal way live CDs mount their filesystems?  Wouldn't "toram=yes" make boot incredibly slow and use more memory than the usual approach of aufs, etc?

Comment: He may be wanting to decompress the sqaushfs and other components to RAM so you can remove the boot media. This can be extremely helpful when USB booting a computer with limited USB ports. I wish the feature was not removed and would be added again to the Live CDs.

Comment: Chris is correct.  I want to be able to remove the boot media.  This will be performed on laptops that have no internal CD Rom drive.  I would like to be able to remove the connection to the drive once the boot process is complete.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before, add the `toram` option to the grub/grub.cfg file, turning the

`linux ... noeject noprompt --`

boot line into

`linux ... noeject noprompt toram --`

- If you've got the live iso on a usb drive with a FS that's writable it's a lot easier, just mount & edit the grub file.
- If you're using a cd/dvd or just `dd`'ing the iso straight to a usb then you'll have to edit the iso file before writing it, changing the grub file first and then write to cd/usb. I once found a nice little gui program that could do that, could've been `isomaster` but not sure. Or extract files -> edit -> make new iso with anything like mkisofs, k3b, brasero, etc.

(FYI, I can't recommend `dd`'ing an iso to usb, less than optimal and shreds the usb's MBR/fat)

Using the `toram` option is different from the regular overlayfs (formerly aufs?) that all Ubuntu (all Debian too?) live iso's use. This option copies all the needed data from the cd/dvd/usb into ram, so you can remove or edit the cd/usb, and generally run with ram FS read/write speeds (+2GB/sec) instead of cd/usb speeds (1-10MB/sec). But the expense is using up about a GB of ram.

Answer (score 0):

All live CDs "boot to RAM".

That is, for any volatile storage they use RAM.

This is technically achieved using a **union filesystem** such as *aufs* which allows you to mount a read-only filesystem (eg, the CD) and combine it with free RAM to enable writes, but the writes are gone when the computer is rebooted.  This may also be combined with a compressed filesystem (such as squashfs) so that the read-only filesystem can be compressed and thus fit more data.

If you have any specific needs in terms of *how* you want to mount the filesystem, you'll have to be more specific.