# Is it possible to burn DVD from live DVD?

Tags: system-installation, dvd, livedvd

Soon I will have new laptop and I will installing Xubuntu 16.04 on it, but I only have old version on DVD disk and my old laptop have broken DVD, is it possible to boot from live DVD and then burn another version of iso on DVD?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You need to boot the live Ubuntu to RAM and then you can access your DVD drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/521319/need-a-live-cd-to-boot-to-ram

Comment: Creating a liveUSB might be easier...